# Proof for convergence of this series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to determine if $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n^2+n+1)}{(n^4+2n+2)}$ converges.

The ratio test in this case is inconclusive so i tried to do something like this.

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n^2+n+1)}{(n^4+2n+2)}\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n^2+n+1)}{(n^4)}$

$\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n^2+n+1)}{(n^4)}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}$.

Since the second series converges so does the first one.

Is this valid, or how can I else prove if the first series converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have
$$0\leq \frac{(n^2+n+1)}{(n^4+2n+2)}\leq \frac{(n^2+n+1)}{(n^4)} = \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^3} + \frac{1}{n^4}.$$
And
$$
\sum\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^3} + \frac{1}{n^4}
$$
is a sum of convergent $p$-series, so it is convergent. Now the original series is convergent by the comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** $$\frac{(n^2+n+1)}{(n^4+2n+2)} \approx \frac{n^2}{n^4} = \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Now use the special comparison test.